# Connecting to MySql on Mac: No suitable driver error

Tags: java, mysql

I am getting the error: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

I have imported the .jar file that is available here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=13598

I am using Eclipse.

I am connecting to the DB with this code:

```
package dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBCon {

    private static final String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost";
    private static final String port = "3306";
    private static final String db = "mydb";
//      private static final String user = "root";
//      private static final String pwd = "";
    private static final String user = "myusername";
    private static final String pwd = "mypwd";

    public Connection getCon() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            String url = host + ":" + port + "/" + db;

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

I then query the DB with this code:

```
package dao;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.sql.Connection;
import model.ClassPojo;

public class ARCSDao {

public ArrayList<ClassPojo> viewClasses() throws SQLException{
    ArrayList<ClassPojo> classList = new ArrayList<ClassPojo>();

    DBCon db = new DBCon();
    Connection con = db.getCon();
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM classes");
    while(rs.next()){
           ClassPojo aClass = new ClassPojo();
           rs.getString("class_name");
           rs.getString("class_uri");
           classList.add(aClass);
    }           
    return classList;
    }
}
```

Comment: I used to do dev on a windows box and had no issues, I am now doing this on a mac - not sure if that causes any issues. I can't see how it can since this is in Java and I have done non-db coding on this machine.

Comment: Is mysql server on the same box? Then how about checking the mysql version you are using?

Comment: No it's not on the same box, I am actually using a remote mysql server using port forwarding, but I'll try to check what version of mysql that is.

Comment: if you wan't to connect to a remote machine you need to change localhost in jdbc:mysql://localhost to the name of your db-host.

Comment: @stacker - I know that would normally make sense. The people who set the remote db up said that they have set up port forwarding so I simply add localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

before

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
```

if this doesn't work double check that the jdbc driver (jar file) is included in your classpath

Comment: Thanks at least I am getting a different error now ; com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure - I will work on this.